# jQuery DataTables Plugin - iDisplayLength

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTables 1.10.10.  I would like to modify the main plugin Javascript to override the iDisplayLength value to -1.  That way ALL my datatables show "All" by default, and the user can filter down if they wish.

Where in the file would this be set?  I'm having trouble finding it.  I've searched for iDisplayLength and tried overriding the value with -1, but it's not taking so I'm guessing it's being set somewhere that I'm not looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  On line 6262 (in my jquery.dataTable.js file at least), before the following code

```
// Map the initialisation options to the settings object
_fnMap( oSettings.oFeatures, oInit, [ .....
```

I added the following line

```
oInit.iDisplayLength = -1;
```

DataTable now loads with show "All" always, even if the report has the iDisplayLength specified on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, changing the source files has main drawbacks. For example, in case you want to update the library, all changes are lost. Why not [creating a personal plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) for the DataTables library. Like:

```
$.fn.myDataTable = function() {    
  $(this).dataTable( {
    "iDisplayLength": -1
  });
};

// call
$( ".allTables" ).myDataTable();
```

Comment: because I need to change it globally for all dataTables in 1 shot.  I need to find where ever the main plugin is setting the length based on the iDisplayLength passed in, and override it to -1

Comment: I understand that. But this would be my preferred way. It's clean and you only have to change all `.dataTable(` occurrences with `.myDataTable(` in your scripts once. Zero problems when migrating to a newer version of dataTables.

Comment: I did not create the webpage I'm working on.  It has dataTables all over the place and each one has it's own init call.  It's not done in a single call, so I would have hundreds of files to update to myDataTable.  I need to override the main jquery.dataTables.js file and set the displaylength to -1 for ALL tables, everywhere without having to change the init call